# Limit of positive definite sequence with terms $a_{n} = \frac{a_{n - 1} + 1}{2}$ or $a_{n} = sin(a_{n - 1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

In the sequence all terms are positive. 
Each term can be either $a_{n} = \frac{a_{n - 1} + 1}{2}$ or $a_{n} = \sin{a_{n - 1}}$.
Can this sequence have a limit in the interval $(0, 1)$?

Comment: What do you think? Suppose it did have a limit? What could it be?

Comment: @Somos $sin(x) < x$ for  $x \in (0, 1)$, probably it mean that since some place we cant have terms of type $sin(a_{n-1})$. Then if the limit exists $a = \frac{a + 1}{2}$ and $a = 1$ not in interval. How to show it strictly?

Comment: I think that your idea to focus on one function or the other is good but I'd focus on $f(x)=(x+1)/2$, rather than on the sine. Then, $f$ moves any point in the interval (some point within $\varepsilon$ of a purported limit, for example) half the way to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Let us use an indirect prrof and assume that we have such a sequence, convergent to $g\in(0,1)$. Then by the definition of convergence $$ \forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists N \,\forall n>N :|a_n-g|<\epsilon$$

Let us take $\epsilon < \min\{\frac{1-g}{4},\frac{g-\sin g}{2}\}$. For $n$ big enough we have $|a_n-g|<\epsilon$ and $|a_{n+1}-g|<\epsilon$. We have two cases.

If $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n+1}{2}$, then
$$ |a_{n+1}-g| = |\frac{a_n+1}{2} - g| = |\frac{a_n-g}{2} + \frac{1-g}{2}| \ge \big| |\frac{1-g}{2}| - |\frac{a_n-g}{2}|\big| \rightarrow^{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1-g}{2}$$
so for $n$ big enough $|a_{n+1}-g| > \frac{1-g}{4} \ge \epsilon$.

If $a_{n+1} = \sin a_n$, then
$$ |a_{n+1}-g| = |\sin a_n - g| \ge \big| |g-\sin g| - |\sin a_n - \sin g|\big| \rightarrow^{n\rightarrow\infty} g-\sin g $$
so for $n$ big enough $|a_{n+1}-g| > \frac{g-\sin g}{2} \ge \epsilon$.

We get a contradiction with the assumption that $|a_{n+1}-g|<\epsilon$.

In conclusion it's impossible to get a convergent series; if one element of the sequence gets close to the would-be limit, then the next one cannot be arbitratily close.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, suppose $a_{2n+1}=\frac{a_{2n} + 1}{2}$ and $a_{2n+2}=\sin(a_{2n+1})$, with $0<a_1$.
If $\lim a_n=L$ exists, we have $L=\frac{L+1}{2}$ and $L=\sin(L)$, i.e., $\sin(1)=1$, which is absurd.

So, the sequence can converge only if there finitely many terms of one of the forms.

Comment: first term can be any positive number, and the sequence may consist entirely of the first type of numbers or of the second

Comment: I'll erase the restriction on $a_1$ because it isn't really necessary. I address your second point on the second paragraph.

Comment: So, as sequence with terms of first type have a limit 1, other sequence of second type have limit 0, we cant have a limit now, right?

Comment: That's right. --